# Finding Table In a Div with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write something that extracts the spreads for NFL scores.  Following [this project](https://github.com/Degentleman/NFL-Results-Scraper/blob/master/NFL%20Results%20Scraper.py) which scrapes pro football reference for all games, I am trying to go one step further.  An example page I want to scrape is the following: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201709070nwe.htm .

My code so far:

```
def get_spread(row):
  a = row.findAll('a',href=True)
  box_link = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/'+a[-1]['href']
  temp_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(box_link),'html.parser')
  table = temp_soup.find('div', {'id':'all_game_info'})
  return table
```

Where row is defined as `soup.findAll('tbody', limit=1)[0].findAll('tr')[0:]`

Ignoring that bit and trying to just scrape that example page, if I use `table = temp_soup.find('div', {'id':'all_game_info'})`, I get that `table` is

```
<div class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented" id="all_game_info">
<div class="section_heading">
<span class="section_anchor" data-label="Game Info" id="game_info_link"></span><h2>Game Info</h2> <div class="section_heading_text">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_game_info">
      
  <table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" id="game_info" data-cols-to-freeze="0"><caption>Game Info Table</caption><tr class="thead onecell" ><td class="right center" data-stat="onecell" colspan="2" >Game Info</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Won Toss</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >Chiefs (deferred)</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Roof</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >outdoors</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Surface</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >fieldturf </td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Duration</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >3:37</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Attendance</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" ><a href="/years/2017/attendance.htm">65,878</a></td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Weather</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >63 degrees, wind 8 mph</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Vegas Line</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >New England Patriots -8.0</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Over/Under</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >47.5 <b>(over)</b></td></tr>

</table>

      </div>
   </div>
-->
</div>
```

I want the last two ('Vegas Line' and 'Over/Under'), however if I run `table.findall('tr')`, it returns None, same as if I try to findall for : 'td', 'table', 'th'.  So I am curious how I can extract those values from the table variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<table>` is located inside HTML comments (`<!-- ... -->`), so additional steps are necessary to extract it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201709070nwe.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('h2:contains("Game Info")').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))

# load <table> from HTML comments <!-- ... -->
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(table), 'html.parser')
vegas_line = soup.select_one('th:contains("Vegas Line")').find_next('td').text
over_under = soup.select_one('th:contains("Over/Under")').find_next('td').text

print(vegas_line)
print(over_under)
```

Prints:

```
New England Patriots -8.0
47.5 (over)
```

Comment: Oh.  Did not know that about HTML.  I assume that is why it doesn't show up in soup.findall('table') as well?

Comment: @yankeefan11 Yes, that's exactly the reason.

Comment: This gives me a 'NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.' with the table = line ?

Comment: @yankeefan11 You're using ancient version of `beautifulsoup`. I'm on version `beautifulsoup4==4.9.1` Try to update the module.

Comment: Thanks.  Google Colab is not up to date.